# Get all the Children in a Grids Column

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, grid

How would I get all of the children in a specific Column of a Grid? I need to perform some calculations on the children inside a certain Column in a Grid, but I cannot find a way of getting all children for that Column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var children = yourGrid.Children.Where(x => (int)x.GetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty) == columnNumber).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do some thing like this

This is the code example

XAML

```
 <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" x:Name="testGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition>
        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"></StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

CODE (c#)

```
for (int i = 0; i < testGrid.Children.Count; i++) {
            if (Grid.GetColumn(((StackPanel)testGrid.Children[i])) == 1) {
                string test = "abcdTest";
            }
        }
```

The oly constraint is you need to keep a check of the kind of elements u place inside the Grid .. if they are different then mapping them will cause trouble ... please let me know if different elements are present.